# Notepad++ last open tag closing

Tags: plugins, notepad++

I am searching for a plugin or any other way for n++ to close the last open tag on demand (i.e. assigned to a shortcut key), not automatically.

Sadly all I could find is tag auto-closing (in TextFX and XMLtools), where a tag closure is added when the user types the '**>**' (like in `<div>`).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything for a tag closure, but if you turn on the auto-completion does that do what you need it to?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I enable auto-completion from the second character, much less obtrusive, but not what I've been looking for. I'll file a feature-request to the developer...

Answer (score 1):

To enable that option (like Coda for Mac, or Aptana)
TextFX -> TextFX Settings -> Autoclose XHTML/XML <tags> :)

Comment: However it "autocompletes" the closing tag when I enter the last `>`. Anyway, I've moved to PHPstorm IDE and it's great.